# Transition solely for one pseudo-class?

Tags: html, css

Pretty straight forward, how do I apply a transition solely to **one** pseudo-class, e.g. `:active`.
Since *both* pseudo-classes change the *same* property, targeting via the property doesn't work, but using for example `active` or `:active` as a selector does either return an error or nothing. [The use case](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/dyMjVxj).

```
.el {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease;
  
  &:hover { background-color: darken(#fff, 2.5%); }
  
  &:active { background-color: darken(#fff, 10%); }
}
```

Or

```
.el {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 100ms ease;
}
.el:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.el:active {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

Comment: add the transtion inside :active (or disable the transition inside the other classes)

Comment: @TemaniAfif. I remember to have tried that... Thanks! Voting to close.